# how to verify difference time between linux machines not greater than 5 seconds

Tags: linux, rhel, date, time, ntp

How may I verify that all machines, `appolo01` - `mars3`, are less than 5 seconds offset from each other?

```
ssh appolo01 date ; ssh appolo02 date ; ssh appolo03 date ; ssh mars1 date ; ssh mars2 date ; ssh mars3 date


Sun Apr 22 09:05:39 UTC 2018
Sun Apr 22 09:05:40 UTC 2018
Sun Apr 22 09:05:40 UTC 2018
Sun Apr 22 09:05:40 UTC 2018
Sun Apr 22 09:05:40 UTC 2018
Sun Apr 22 09:05:48 UTC 2018
```

Comment: Would the `rdate` command be usable to you? Are the hosts running NTP?

Comment: what is the syntax ?

Comment: rdate
Usage: rdate [-s] [-p] [-u] [-l] [-t sec] <host> ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date +%s` to get a UNIX timestamp like `1524388823`. Unlike the locale dependent, human-readable date, this can be compared more easily in a script.

On machines that are properly in sync of time, something like this should work:

```
a=$(date +%s)
b=$(ssh user@remote date +%s)
c=$(date +%s)

if [ $a -le $b  -a  $b -le $c ]
then
    echo Seems to be OK.
fi
```

- `(a)` is the local time before SSH,
- `(b)` is the remote time,
- `(c)` is the local time after SSH.

If `(a <= b <= c)` it's reasonably safe to assume the time is in sync. This is not taking network lag into account at all - check delta(a,c) for that - but it should still be reasonable. Assuming SSH won't ask for a password and/or you won't take all day providing it.

If you still want to add 5 seconds of margin to that, use a-5 and c+5. Of course this allows 5 seconds in either direction - and does not qualify as a 5 second window across all machines. But unless you're actually doing a deep space mission like your host names suggest, there is no reason to accept such a huge time discrepancy in the first place.

If you are using NTP constantly, not just once per year, all machines should be in perfect sync no matter what and most of the time we just blindly assume this to be the case and not even bother to check.

Comment: The best solution would probably be to set up the machines with NTP against a local server, and let that sync its time with the rest of the world.

Comment: The problem of this solution is indeed network lag/system load.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sure. This is meant for a quick check if everything is all-ok, as a second opinion if you want to verify that NTP is doing its thing. NTP exists for a reason, if you want to sync time that is what you use.

Comment: @frostschutz Nonetheless, I did however have NAGIOS checks for detecting time drifts, and believe me we detected them. Things can go wrong with many things. That reminds me, NTP utils take in account network lag. If doing that against an NTP server instead of doing an ssh date, you *may* get slightly better results.